# SPARQL return instances not linked to a set of classes - query returns all instances instead of only one

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf, knowledge-graph

A small example ontology

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .


:Product a owl:Class .
:Accessories rdfs:subClassOf :Product .
:hasAccessories a rdf:Property .
:hasAccessories  rdfs:domain :Product.
:hasAccessories  rdfs:range :Accessories.
 
:Mouse rdfs:subClassOf :Accessories.
:Keyboard rdfs:subClassOf :Accessories.

:Computer rdfs:subClassOf :Product .
:Desktop rdfs:subClassOf :Computer .
:Laptop rdfs:subClassOf :Computer .

:m1 a :Mouse .
:m2 a :Mouse .
:k1 a :Keyboard .
:k2 a :Keyboard .  # linked wrongly
:k3 a :Keyboard .  # linked not at all
:c1 a :Computer .
:c2 a :Computer .
:d1 a :Desktop .
:d2 a :Desktop .
:l1 a :Laptop .

:s a :Storage

:c1 :hasAccessories :m1 , :k1 .
:d1 :hasAccessories :m1 .
:d2 :hasAccessories :m2 .
:s :hasAccessories :k2 # <---- Note this is intentional bad design
```

I want to retrieve `k2` as the only non-*Computer*-bound Accessory.

I do not have a reasoning so this query does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a WHERE
{
  ?c a :Computer. 
  ?a a :Accessories . 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?c :hasAccessories ?a .}
}
```

Output: Empty

---

If not for the `Storage s` I could do this query to get all non-linked Accessories

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?c ?a WHERE
{  
  ?acc rdfs:subClassOf* :Accessories .
  ?a a ?acc . 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?c :hasAccessories ?a .}
}
```

Output: Empty

---

Going over the inheritances via this query does not filter out any of my results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a WHERE
{ 
  ?computer rdfs:subClassOf* :Computer .
  ?c a ?computer. 
  
  ?acc rdfs:subClassOf* :Accessories .
  ?a a ?acc . 

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?c :hasAccessories ?a .}
}
```

Output:
`k1, k2, m1, m2`

I have a vague feeling why it happens, e.g. it would find the negative example `l1 not hasAccessory k1`, which puts `k1` into the results.
How do I need to adjust my query to only result in `k2` **without making use of the storage in anyway**, i.e. check *only* for subClassesOf Computer?

Comment: a query that follows more the natural language description of your task would be `SELECT DISTINCT ?a WHERE
{

  ?acc rdfs:subClassOf* :Accessories .
  ?a a ?acc .

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?c :hasAccessories ?a ; a/rdfs:subClassOf* :Computer}
}` - but this also returns `m2` because it's attached to `d2` for which we do not know if it's a computer or not.

Comment: @UninformedUser works perfectly! Need to wrap my head around the case why I must add the Computer to the FILTER but I think I am nearly there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by UninformedUser this works for the two special cases (unbound and not-bound by computer):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a WHERE {    
   ?a a/rdfs:subClassOf* :Accessories .   
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
         ?c a/rdfs:subClassOf* :Computer;
            :hasAccessories ?a . 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you are selecting all the things that are computers and all the things that are accessories, given that they are not linked.

What you want instead is to select all the things that are accessories and the things they are linked to, given that those are not computers. So flip the conditions:

```
SELECT ?non-computer ?acc WHERE {
  ?acc a/rdfs:subClassOf* :Accessories .
  ?non-computer :hasAccessories ?acc .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?non-computer a/rdfs:subClassOf* :Computer
  }
}
```

You may not actually need to check whether `?acc` is an accessory (ie. belongs to a subclass of `:Accessories`), being the object in a `:hasAccessories` tuple should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. I just introduced a second case k3 of an unbound accessory which I would like to cover as well.

Comment: @Daraan That'll be a separate query - you select any accessory that has no link to anything. You can then [`UNION`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/UNION) those results